# How to send an email on ssis package failure?

Tags: ssis

My requirement is I need to send an email with error details if any one of the components used in my package got failed.

Tried googling and read regarding precedence constraints and event handlers in ssis but my package is large and is having many components(control flow items).

Can we define many event handlers for each executables used in package?if so, I thnk defining event handler for each component is not a good performance i think.

Please suggest the best way to do this......

Answer (score 1):

You can use Script task to send your own custom email in SSIS package
In this you need to set configuration read witter variable as a parameter to send custom email

edit script and write this code to script

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Net.Mail;


    [System.AddIn.AddIn("ScriptMain", Version = "1.0", Publisher = "", Description = "")]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {
        #region VSTA generated code
        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };  
        #endregion


        #region VSTA generated code
        /*enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };*/
        #endregion

        /*
        The execution engine calls this method when the task executes.
        To access the object model, use the Dts property. Connections, variables, events,
        and logging features are available as members of the Dts property as shown in the following examples.

        To reference a variable, call Dts.Variables["MyCaseSensitiveVariableName"].Value;
        To post a log entry, call Dts.Log("This is my log text", 999, null);
        To fire an event, call Dts.Events.FireInformation(99, "test", "hit the help message", "", 0, true);

        To use the connections collection use something like the following:
        ConnectionManager cm = Dts.Connections.Add("OLEDB");
        cm.ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Provider=SQLNCLI10;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;";

        Before returning from this method, set the value of Dts.TaskResult to indicate success or failure.

        To open Help, press F1.
    */

        public void Main()
        {
            string sSubject = "Integration Task Result"; 

            int iPriority = 2;

            if (SendMail(sSubject, iPriority))
            {
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
            }
            else
            {
                //Fails the Task
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
            }
        }
        public bool SendMail(string sSubject,int iPriority)
        {
            try
            {
                string Email_Server = Dts.Variables["Email_Server"].Value.ToString();
                string Email_Port = Dts.Variables["Email_Port"].Value.ToString();
                string Form_Email_User = Dts.Variables["Form_Email_User"].Value.ToString();
                string From_Pass = Dts.Variables["From_Pass"].Value.ToString();
                string To_Email = Dts.Variables["To_Email"].Value.ToString();       
                string CC_Email = Dts.Variables["CC_Email"].Value.ToString();
                string From_Email = Dts.Variables["From_Email"].Value.ToString();
                string Email_FromName = Dts.Variables["Email_FromName"].Value.ToString();


                string TaskID = Dts.Variables["TaskID"].Value.ToString();
                string TaskName = Dts.Variables["TaskName"].Value.ToString();
                string FailedConfigurations = Dts.Variables["FailedConfigurations"].Value.ToString();
                string PackageName = Dts.Variables["PackageName"].Value.ToString();
                string StartTime = Dts.Variables["StartTime"].Value.ToString();
                string CreatorComputerName = Dts.Variables["CreatorComputerName"].Value.ToString();
                string UserName = Dts.Variables["UserName"].Value.ToString();



                String sBody = "StartTime = " + StartTime +
                     "<br/>TaskID = " + TaskID +
                     "<br/>TaskName = " + TaskName +
                     "<br/>UserName = " + UserName +
                     "<br/>CreatorComputerName = " + CreatorComputerName +
                     "<br/>PackageName = " + PackageName;

                if (FailedConfigurations.Equals(""))
                {
                    sBody = sBody + "<br/><br/>Task Execution failure";
                } else {
                    sBody = sBody + "<br/><br/>FailedConfigurations = " + FailedConfigurations;
                }


                SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
                MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

                MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress(From_Email, Email_FromName);

                //You can have multiple emails separated by ;
                string[] sEmailTo = Regex.Split(To_Email, ";");
                string[] sEmailCC = Regex.Split(CC_Email, ";");
                int sEmailServerSMTP = int.Parse(Email_Port);

                smtpClient.Host = Email_Server;
                smtpClient.Port = sEmailServerSMTP;
                smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;

                System.Net.NetworkCredential myCredentials =
                new System.Net.NetworkCredential(Form_Email_User, From_Pass);
                smtpClient.Credentials = myCredentials;

                message.From = fromAddress;

                if (sEmailTo != null)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < sEmailTo.Length; ++i)
                    {
                        if (sEmailTo[i] != null && sEmailTo[i] != "")
                        {
                            message.To.Add(sEmailTo[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (sEmailCC != null)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < sEmailCC.Length; ++i)
                    {
                        if (sEmailCC[i] != null && sEmailCC[i] != "")
                        {
                            message.To.Add(sEmailCC[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }   
                switch (iPriority)
                {
                    case 1:
                        message.Priority = MailPriority.High;
                    break;
                    case 3:
                        message.Priority = MailPriority.Low;
                    break;
                    default:
                        message.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;
                    break;
                }
                message.Subject = sSubject;
                message.IsBodyHtml = true;
                message.Body = sBody;

                smtpClient.Send(message);
                return true;    
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the event handler tab to set what you want to happen in a particular event. You can choose events at any level in the package (i.e. across the whole package or just on a particular executable). Within the event handler, add a send email task.